# writing data to a file with the result is not as expected

Tags: c#

I use this code to write a string to a file.

```
var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
var sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
sw.Write(dataString);
fs.Flush();
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

When I debug it, I see the dataString correct. However, after writing to a file, there are some strings have wrong orders. Should I add a thread Sleep after writing data to the file because right after writing data to the file, I read it back for other process.

OR probably there is better way to write a string to a file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "have wrong orders"? Please be specific.

Comment: some characters are not as in the original string after writing to the file.

Comment: @devn: I doubt that this is the case. More likely is that you are mistaken. Please provide a **full, complete**, minimal working code example that demonstrates the problem, and that we can all run and reproduce the problem. If simplifying the code makes the problem go away, chances are the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OR probably there is better way to write a string to a file?

Yes, there's a simpler way. Use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376.aspx) or [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143357.aspx).

```
File.WriteAllText("output.txt", text, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Apart from being more concise, another advantage is that the file will be correctly closed even if there is an exception. However, I doubt that it will change the order in which the data is written to the file.